# Generalised Case for Expected Value of Children to get a boy and a girl

Tags: probability, expected-value

Source: (Harvard Statistics 110: see #17, p. 29 of pdf).

A couple decides to keep having children until they have at least one boy and at least one girl, and then stop. Assume they never have twins, that the "trials" are independent with probability 1/2 of a boy, and that they are fertile enough to keep producing children indefinitely. What is the expected number of children?

I would like to answer this question more generally with 
the probability of a boy being $p$ and the probability of a girl being $q$.

Let $C$ be a random variable denoting the number of children born until at least one boy and at least one girl is born.

Let $B$ be a random variable denoting the number of boys born until the first girl.

Let $G$ be a random variable denoting the number of girls born until the first boy.

Then the probability of $C$, the number of children being equal to $k$ is 
$$p^{k-1}q+q^{k-1}p$$

So

$$E(C)=q\sum_{k=2}^\infty kp^{k-1}+p\sum_{k=2}^\infty kq^{k-1}$$
$$=q \frac{d}{dp}(\frac{p^2}{1-p})+p\frac{d}{dq}(\frac{q^2}{1-q})$$
$$=1+\frac{p^2+q^2}{pq}$$

However, we could also think of the problem as $C=B+G$.

Now $$E(C)=E(B)+E(G)$$ however I cannot obtain my previous expression.

Comment: I don't understand your second method.  If you want an alternate method using Expectation directly:   Let $E_B,E_G$ be the expected number of kids before you get a boy, girl (resp.).  then $E=p\times (E_G+1)+q\times (E_B+1)$.

Comment: Total Children = Number of Boys Born + Number of Girls Born. So I thought this would be an intuitive way to use expectation.

Comment: I still don't get it.  How are you embedding the condition that you stop once you have at least one of each?

Comment: So P(B)=2 would be $p^2q$ for example. Its  assumed that the condition has been embedded?

Comment: Perhaps instead defining B to be the number of boys before the first girl, and G the number of girls before the first boy is appropriate. So the case mentioned in my question would have been dealt with in the G variable, where G=1,2,...

Comment: However $p/q+q/p$ does not get $E(C)$

Comment: I don't think this makes sense, sorry.  Try writing it out carefully.  With proper definitions of everything.

Comment: Note: it's worth studying the method I sketched.  This approach comes in very handy, especially if you have multiple "types" you are searching for (boy, girl being the case of two types).   Infinite series really don't work well beyond the $2$ type case.

Comment: Does your solution match with mine?

Comment: I didn't finish the calculation.  Should be easy though...just standard bernoulli calculation so $E_B=\frac 1p, E_G=\frac 1q$.

Comment: No , it does not match yours.  Yours is incorrect.  For the case $p=q=\frac 12$ the answer is $3$, not $2$ as your method gives.

Comment: So what is wrong with my method?

Comment: I'm not going to review your calculation line by line.  That's one reason I object to falling back on Infinite Series...it is extremely error prone.  Convince yourself that the answer is $3$ for $p=q=\frac 12$ and confirm that your answer says it is $2$.  That shows you there is an error.  Now, go through your algebra step by step.

Comment: Corrected answer.

Comment: Yes, that one matches (as you should easily be able to verify).